# Matcher Find nth Match Indexes

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I'm trying to get the indexes for each pattern that I find in a document. So far I have:

```
    String temp = "This is a test to see HelloWorld in a test that sees HelloWorld in a test";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("HelloWorld");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
    int current = 0;
    int start;
    int end;

    while (matcher.find()) {
        start = matcher.start(current);
        end = matcher.end(current);
        System.out.println(temp.substring(start, end));
        current++;
    }
```

For some reason **it keeps finding only the first instance of `HelloWorld` in `temp`** though which results in an infinite loop. To be honest, I wasn't sure if you could use `matcher.start(current)` and `matcher.end(current)` - it was just a wild guess because `matcher.group(current)` worked before. This time I need the actual indexes though so `matcher.group()` wouldn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the regex to look like this:

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    start = matcher.start();
    end = matcher.end();
    System.out.println(temp.substring(start, end));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't pass the index to `start(int)` and `end(int)`. The API states that the parameter is the group number. In your case, only zero is correct. Use `start()` and `end()` instead.

The matcher will move to the next match on each iteration because of your call to [`find()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29):

> This method starts at the beginning of the input sequence or, if a previous invocation of the method was successful and the matcher has not since been reset, at the first character not matched by the previous match.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line of code.

```
 start = matcher.start(current);
```

`current` is 1 after first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need the start and end offsets of your matched text, you don't need the current group, this will be ok:

```
    String temp = "This is a test to see HelloWorld in a test that sees HelloWorld in a test";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("HelloWorld");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(temp);
    int current = 0;

    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(temp.substring(matcher.start(), matcher.end()));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (matcher.find()) {
    start = matcher.start();
    end = matcher.end();
    System.out.println(temp.substring(start, end));
}
```

Will do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String temp = "This is a test to see HelloWorld in a test that sees HelloWorld in a test";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("HelloWorld");
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(temp);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(temp.substring(m.start(), m.stop()));
    }
```